# Passing child props to child component in Gatsby V2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Since upgrading to using Gatsby V2 I have been struggling to pass `this.state` to child components to be used as `this.props`.

For Example I have a Container that has `data1` and `data2` added to `this.state` as

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data1: '',
      data2: ''
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
   // Loading database
   .then(doc =>
    this.setState({
      data1: doc.data().data1,
      data2: doc.data().data2
    })
  );
}
  render() {
    const children = this.props;
    const stateAsProps = React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        data1: this.state.data1,
        data2: this.state.data2
      })
    );

    return (
        <div>{stateAsProps}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

and a child component as

```
class Child extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.data1}</h1>
      <p>{this.props.data2}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

and finally this is brought into the page by

```
const Page = () => (
  <Parent authUserID="01234" campaignID="56789">
    <Child />
  </Parent>
);
```

In Gatsby V1 this was working but now with the migration I am receiving an error `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {authUserID, campaignID, children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Can anyone advise to why and how this issue can be rectified?

Comment: Try to write `const { children } = this.props;` instead of `const children = this.props;`

Comment: Man I feel dumb. Yes, and thank you. If you add this as an answer I'll be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the entire props object as children in your `Parent` component. Make sure you destructure out the `children` object from the props instead and it will work as expected.

```
const { children } = this.props;
```